# Tally values in a list of JSON records and write to a Dictionary

Tags: c#

I'm reading a JSON file with the following simple structure and I need to tally the 'Ord Qty' for each record with the same 'Ord No' field, and store the total in another lookup list with a single record for every 'Ord No'. The input file looks like

```
[
  {
    "Ord No": "41035",
    "Ord Date": "05/06/2021",
    "Stock No": "TW2807",
    "Ord Qty": "3"
  },
  {
    "Ord No": "41035",
    "Ord Date": "05/06/2021",
    "Stock No": "TW2809",
    "Ord Qty": "1"
  },
  {
    "Ord No": "41035",
    "Ord Date": "05/06/2021",
    "Stock No": "TW280S",
    "Ord Qty": "3"
  },
  {
    "Ord No": "41034",
    "Ord Date": "05/06/2021",
    "Stock No": "TW290L",
    "Ord Qty": "17"
  },
  {
    "Ord No": "41034",
    "Ord Date": "05/06/2021",
    "Stock No": "TW2830S",
    "Ord Qty": "2"
  },
  {
    "Ord No": "41034",
    "Ord Date": "05/06/2021",
    "Stock No": "CCDW12",
    "Ord Qty": "15"
  },
  {
    "Ord No": "41034",
    "Ord Date": "05/06/2021",
    "Stock No": "APXCSS",
    "Ord Qty": "12"
  }
]
```

I need to transform the data into another structure, and to be able to reference it with a key pair i.e.

```
public class OrderTally
{
    public string OrdNo { get; set; }
    public string TotalOrdQty { get; set; }
}
```

...for the structure, and I'm looking to end up with this, which I will use as a look up.

```
[
  {
    "Ord No": "41035",
    "Total Ord Qty": "7"
  },
  {
    "Ord No": "41034",
    "Total Ord Qty": "29"
  }
]
```

I originally I thought I needed to be using System.Collections.Dictionary class to be doing this, but the code I've produced so far hasn't even gotten me close to where I'm successfully tallying the quantity for the new record.

I'm reading the serialized JSON into a string and parsing as follows

```
public class OrdsIn
{
    [JsonProperty("Ord No")]
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Ord Date")]
    public string OrderDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Stock No")]
    public string StockNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Ord Qty")]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
}


List<Order> OrdsIn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(inString);
Dictionary<string, List<OrderTally>> keyup = new Dictionary<string, List<OrderTally>>();
```

Comment: How are you parsing the json? Can you post a [mre] of that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily solved by using the following 3 classes.

```
public class OrderRecord
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Ord No")]
    public int OrdNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Ord Date")]
    public DateTime OrdDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Stock No")]
    public string StockNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Ord Qty")]
    public int OrdQty { get; set; }
}

public class OrderTally
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Ord No")]
    public string OrdNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Total Ord Qty")]
    public string TotalOrdQty { get; set; }
}

public class JsonUtils
{
    public static string GetJsonOfOrderTally(string strJsonRecords)
    {
        List<OrderRecord> lstOrderRecord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OrderRecord>>(strJsonRecords);

        List<OrderTally> lstOrderTally = lstOrderRecord.GroupBy(d => d.OrdNo)
                                          .Select(g => new OrderTally
                                          {
                                              OrdNo = g.Key.ToString(),
                                              TotalOrdQty = g.Sum(s => s.OrdQty).ToString(),
                                          }).ToList();
        string strJsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstOrderTally, Formatting.Indented);

        return strJsonResult;
    }
}
```

You implement it by the following code.

```
string strJsonResult = JsonUtils.GetJsonOfOrderTally(strJsonRecords);
```

Then, you will get the following result.

```
[
  {
    "Ord No": "41035",
    "Total Ord Qty": "7"
  },
  {
    "Ord No": "41034",
    "Total Ord Qty": "46"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Ming. thanks for replying. At the moment, I'm getting a compiler error 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'in' to 'string for the line  'TotalOrdQty = g.Sum(s => s.OrdQty).ToString()'

Comment: Hi Gary, I built a project and tested it works correctly, and then I sent a copy of some code needed. Maybe, you seem to write something wrong.

Comment: Sorry Ming - you're quite right. I changed a data type elsewhere in my solution! this works, and I'll mark my question as answered.